# multiple form actions, return any validation errors and refresh results on successful submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have a table filled from the database. Each row has a checkbox. When you select (multiple) checkboxes i want to be able to press:

- one button to change $row->status for all checked rows
- another button to convert each checked row's contents into form elements.(i've been doing this by choosing different templates in the view depending on if `isset($_POST['ap'])`)
- then i will need a submit button to save any changes to these rows.

I am using codeigniter and have been using [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit forms.

My main problem is combining the two functions below and making the code as reusable as possible (i have a few similar pages for different data). `$('.form_js')` feeds back `validation_errors();` but it doesn't allow for different table actions.

Thanks in advance

**Here's my current code:**

```
$('.form_js').submit(function(){ 

    var options = { target: $(this).find(".error")}; 

    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});

function form_action(controller){

    var original_url = window.location;
    var form = $("#ap_table");
    var list = $(':checkbox[name="ap[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');
    alert(base_url + controller + "?ap=" + list);
    form.attr('action', base_url + controller + "?ap_id=" + list);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with a fresh mind and this code.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function()
{
var form = $("#numbers");
var submit_button = $(this).attr('value');

if(submit_button == 'Cancel' || submit_button == 'Pause')
{
    var controller = 'numbers/status_msg/' + submit_button;
    var list = $(':checkbox[name="phone_id[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');

    form.attr('action', base_url + controller + '?ids=' + list);
}

/*if($(this).attr('value') == 'Multi Edit')
{
    //allow form to submit to default action '#'
}*/

if($(this).attr('value') == 'Save All')
{
    var controller = 'numbers/multi_update/';
    var options = { target: $(form).find(".error")}; 

    form.attr('action', base_url + controller );

    alert(form.attr('action'));
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    return false;
}

});
```

then in 'numbers/multi_update' load view on successful submission with:

```
if($("input[name=redirect]").val())
{
     //Add $insert_id to the redirect url       
     var redirect_url = $("input[name=redirect]").val() + "/<?php echo $insert_id; ?>"; 

     //redirect
     window.location = base_url + redirect_url;

}
```

This works but is there an easier way?